# OpenGL ES - how to create a plane emitting light

Tags: android, opengl-es

I'm a newbie in the OpenGL ES world, and learning some basics on 3d graphics on Android OpenGL ES. I'm wondering how to create a image plane that emitting light? This is easy to be implemented in 3d model software like Blender (using the Cycles Render), see the image below for effects I'm looking for. Through some research, I learnt that they may be related to Blur or Bloom effect using shader. But I'm not very sure, and I don't know how to implement them.

[image]

Comment: What you see in that image is global illumination, with a textured rectangular light source. More or less the opposite of *basic* 3D graphics, especially in a limited environment like Android OpenGL ES.

Answer (score 2):

As per Paul-Jan's comment, what you want is far from basic in OpenGL.

The default approach for OpenGL is forward rendering. i.e. every time you specify a piece of geometry the calculation goes forwards from triangle to pixels, a function is applied to determine the colour for each of those pixels and they're forwarded to the frame buffer. So the starting position is that each individual pixel has no concept of the world around it. Each exists in isolation.

In your scene, the floor below the box has no idea it should be blue because it has no idea that there is a box above it.

Programs like Blender use a different approach, which in this context could accurate be called backwards rendering. It starts from each pixel and asks what geometry lies behind it. In doing that it explicitly has an idea of all the geometry in the scene. So when it spots that the floor is behind a certain position it can then continue and ask "and which light sources can the floor see?" to establish lighting.

The default OpenGL approach is long established for real-time rendering. If you look at old video games you'll notice evidence of it all over the place: objects often don't cast shadows on each other (or such shadows are very rough approximations), there's only one source of light which is infinitely far away (i.e. it's in a fixed position as far as geometry is concerned; no need to know about the scene really).

So solutions are to invest the geometry with some knowledge of the whole scene. A common approach is to perform internal renderings of the scene from the point of view of the light source. That generates a depth buffer. By handing the light position and depth buffer off to every piece of geometry in the scene they can calculate whether they're visible to the light source. If so then they're illuminated by it. If not then they're not.

Another option is deferred rendering; you do a standard pass of your scene, populating at each pixel the depth, the surface colour, the surface normal, etc. So you get the full scene information broken down into pixel-by-pixel storage from the point of view of the camera. You then pretend that everything the camera can see is everything that there is. So you just need to pass that buffer around for pixels to be able to work out, approximately, which light sources they can and can't see. You can also have different parts of the screen only consider which lights they're close enough to by a broad-phase 2d distance check, which saves time.

In either case we're actually talking about relatively advanced OpenGL stuff.